# Can I remotely visit elasticsearch-head-master?

Tags: elasticsearch

I've deployed a elasticsearch-head-master on a remote server, but i wanna visit it in another win-PC. I've found that In default settings, **I can't visit the head-master via http://serverIp:9100(got a 500 Internal Privoxy Error)**. I wanna visit head-master via http://serverIp:9100 instead of localhost:9100. Is there any conf file I can adjust to achieve this?  Thanks!

Comment: Can you try setting network.host in elasticsearch yaml to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, I've already got a solution to this:

modify the **Gruntfile.js**, and add **hostname: '*' to tag connect/server/option **[here is a image shows how to do this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGdFt.jpg)